# Egorov's theorem and Baire class $1$ function

Tags: analysis

Suppose $f$ is Baire class 1. Then there exists $f_n$ each one is continuous and that $f_n \to f$. By Egorov's theorem, a measurable $\mu(B) < \varepsilon$, and $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ uniformly on the relative complement $A \setminus B$.

(1) Can we make the set $B$ to include the set of discontinuous point of $f$?

(2) Can we construct $g_n$ where the rate of convergence on $B$ is slowest?

Comment: Then what additional assumption will be needed?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the first question is no. Say $K$ is compact, has empty  interior, no isolated points, and positive measure (for example a fat Cantor set). Let $f=\chi_K$. Then $f$ is in Baire class 1. But $f$ is discontinuous at every point of $K$. So you can't include all the discontinuities of $f$ in $B$ if $\epsilon<m(K)$.

The second question doesn't make much sense, since you don't give any relation between $g_n$ and $f_n$. Were the $g_n$ supposed to be a subsequence of $f_n$ or something? (Once we make sense of the question the answer will be no - there's never a slowest anything...)

Comment: Then what condition on $f$ is needed to make (1) true?

Comment: It's obvious true if and only if $f$ is continuous almost everywhere.

Comment: Then how about (2)? want to show existence of such $g_n$.

Comment: ??? I _said_ in my answer that I didn't understand what you meant by (2). When you say "how about (2)?" that doesn't really clarify things much...